# Need Help Using Device Policy Manager

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Good morning, I need the help of someone here in StackOverflow to create my kiosk mode app.

I tried to find the solution to create the kiosk mode app but nothing worked.

I need to develop this app in Visual Studio with Xamarin.

My requirement is to hide the home bar.  I tried with this:

```
[Activity(Label = "app", MainLauncher = true, ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen")]
```

This hides the bar, but when someone drags the bar to the top it reappears and the user can close it.

I found a solution for Java but I can't convert to Xamarin.

Please can you help me?

Regards,
Andrea

Update:

I tried this:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Permission = "android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN")]
[MetaData("android.app.device_admin", Resource = "@xml/device_admin")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED", Intent.ActionMain })]
public class DeviceAdmin : DeviceAdminReceiver
{

}
```

I tried to launch this command via `adb` but it gime me this error:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell dpm set-device-owner app.app/.MainActivity
usage: dpm [subcommand] [options]
usage: dpm set-active-admin [ --user <USER_ID> ] <COMPONENT>
usage: dpm set-device-owner <COMPONENT>
usage: dpm set-profile-owner [ --user <USER_ID> ] <COMPONENT>

dpm set-active-admin: Sets the given component as active admin for an existing user.

dpm set-device-owner: Sets the given component as active admin, and its package as device owner.

dpm set-profile-owner: Sets the given component as active admin and profile  owner for an existing user.

Error: Unknown admin: ComponentInfo{Tabdealer.Tabdealer/Tabdealer.Tabdealer.MainActivity}
```

My activity is:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Permission = "android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN")]
    [MetaData("android.app.device_admin", Resource = "@xml/device_admin")]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED", Intent.ActionMain })]
    public class DeviceAdmin : DeviceAdminReceiver
    { 

    }
```

deviceadmin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-policies>
    <limit-password />
    <watch-login />
    <reset-password />
    <force-lock />
    <wipe-data />
    <expire-password />
    <encrypted-storage />
    <disable-camera />
  </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

But I don't know how to use `DevicePolicyManager`.

Comment: Just running in fullscreen mode does not make an app into a `COSU` (i.e. a *true* kiosk mode app) and a user will always be able to exit it (unless the device is rooted, but thats a different story). Running 6.0+ you have the ability to set an app as a device owner and enabling `LockTask` mode. There is also `Pinned` mode which is simpler to setup and does not require device ownership, but if the user can access the hardware buttons of the device they can exit the app.

Comment: i have 6.0+ on my tablet.and i am trying to do this locktask mode.can you help me how can i implement this?thanks

Comment: i tried with:StartLockTask(); this block the bar and i can't unlock it with pinned but i need to hide the bar and don't show it never.thanks

Comment: If you have already enable device ownership for your app, then you can use the `DevicePolicyManager` to `SetStatusBarDisabled`, consult https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html#create-dpc

Comment: HI sushihangover i answer under here.can you explain me please?thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I've only been at it for a couple days but I think I can help you.

I'm assuming you registered your device admin receiver in code and did not share it. If not you need to do something like this.

```
DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager)GetSystemService(Context.DevicePolicyService);
ComponentName deviceAdminComponent = new ComponentName(this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(DeviceAdmin)));
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ActionAddDeviceAdmin);
intent.PutExtra(DevicePolicyManager.ExtraDeviceAdmin, deviceAdminComponent);
intent.PutExtra(DevicePolicyManager.ExtraAddExplanation, "Device administrator");
StartActivity(intent);
```

I think you defined this command incorrectly.

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner app.app/.MainActivity
```

After `adb shell dpm set-device-owner` it should be `PackageName`/`.DeviceAdminReceiverName`

If you right-click the android project and look under the *Android Manifest* tab it should tell you the Package Name. If yours says `app.app` then you got the first part correct. While your poking around make sure your `device_admin.xml` is marked as an Android Resource in visual studio.

Debug your `deviceAdminComponent` to make sure your using the full name. Yours will be different but it will look something like this.

[image]

Then include the full name of your `DeviceAdmin` in the adb shell command.

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner app.app/md50db01e1d47836fa6db48b854d43dd279.DeviceAdmin
```

Now next time you restart the application all administrative features will be available. Such as;

```
 devicePolicyManager.SetLockTaskPackages(deviceAdminComponent, new[] { PackageName });
 StartLockTask();
```

At last you can hide the status bar with flags. That doesn't require any administrative privileges though.

```
Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.ForceNotFullscreen);
```